# Названия компьютерных программ

Tags: пунктуация

Не знаю, может, подобный вопрос уже был. Почему названия компьютерных программ не берутся в кавычки?

Answer (score 2):

Названия компьютерных программ (и не только) латинскими символами принято писать без кавычек: MS Word, Excel. Кириллицей - в кавычках: "1С: Предприятие".

Comment: Это да. Но автор про иноязычные названия не упоминал.

Comment: Согласна. Надо конкретизировать вопрос по максимуму.

Answer (score 0):

А вы точно занете, что не берутся? Примеры можно?

Answer (score 0):

Калька с английского. А в англоязычной документации (рекламе прогр. продукта и прочих описаниях) кавычки в названиях используются довольно редко.

Сравните, к примеру, две статьи из "Википедии" о британской газете "Таймс", на русском и на английском языке.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times

В английском варианте статьи название газеты пишется **без кавычек** и выделяется курсивом. *The Times*.

Comment: Nikolja, давайте все-таки не путать названия назет и программ. Касательно слова "калька", я уж просто устал объяснять, что этот термин имеет вполне определенное значение.